# Spark 1.6: drop column in DataFrame with escaped column names

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Trying to drop a column in a DataFrame, but i have column names with dots in them, which I escaped.

Before I escape, my schema looks like this:

```
root
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- hourOfWeek: string (nullable = true)
 |-- observed: string (nullable = true)
 |-- raw.hourOfDay: long (nullable = true)
 |-- raw.minOfDay: long (nullable = true)
 |-- raw.dayOfWeek: long (nullable = true)
 |-- raw.sensor2: long (nullable = true)
```

If I try to drop a column, I get:

```
df = df.drop("hourOfWeek")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'raw.hourOfDay' given input columns raw.dayOfWeek, raw.sensor2, observed, raw.hourOfDay, hourOfWeek, raw.minOfDay, user_id;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:53)
```

Note that I'm not even trying to drop on the columns with dots in name.
Since I couldn't seem to do much without escaping the column names, I converted the schema to:

```
root
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- hourOfWeek: string (nullable = true)
 |-- observed: string (nullable = true)
 |-- `raw.hourOfDay`: long (nullable = true)
 |-- `raw.minOfDay`: long (nullable = true)
 |-- `raw.dayOfWeek`: long (nullable = true)
 |-- `raw.sensor2`: long (nullable = true)
```

but that doesn't seem to help. I still get the same error.

I tried escaping all column names, and drop using the escaped name, but that doesn't work either.

```
root
 |-- `user_id`: long (nullable = true)
 |-- `hourOfWeek`: string (nullable = true)
 |-- `observed`: string (nullable = true)
 |-- `raw.hourOfDay`: long (nullable = true)
 |-- `raw.minOfDay`: long (nullable = true)
 |-- `raw.dayOfWeek`: long (nullable = true)
 |-- `raw.sensor2`: long (nullable = true)

df.drop("`hourOfWeek`")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'user_id' given input columns `user_id`, `raw.dayOfWeek`, `observed`, `raw.minOfDay`, `raw.hourOfDay`, `raw.sensor2`, `hourOfWeek`;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:60)
```

Is there another way to drop a column that would not fail on this type of data?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Alright, I seem to have found the solution after all:

`df.drop(df.col("raw.hourOfWeek"))` seems to work

Comment: Useful answer. But I have one more similar question. Assume that I have around 100 columns in a Spark Dataframe. Is there any way to select only few columns from this dataframe and create another dataframe with those selected columns ? something like df2 = df1.select(df.col("col1", "col2"))

Comment: i think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131716/scala-spark-dataframe-dataframe-select-multiple-columns-given-a-sequence-of-co answers your question

Answer (score 5):

```
val data = df.drop("Customers");
```

will work fine for normal columns

```
val new = df.drop(df.col("old.column"));
```