# Scala Spark DataFrame : dataFrame.select multiple columns given a Sequence of column names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

```
val columnName=Seq("col1","col2",....."coln");
```

Is there a way to do dataframe.select operation to get dataframe containing only the column names specified . 
I know I can do `dataframe.select("col1","col2"...)`
but the `columnName`is generated at runtime.
I could do `dataframe.select()` repeatedly for each column name in a loop.Will it have any performance overheads?. Is there any other simpler way to accomplish this?

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938770/upacking-a-list-to-select-multiple-columns-from-a-spark-data-frame

Comment: @stuart That is a duplicate of this question. See the timeline.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
val columnNames = Seq("col1","col2",....."coln")

// using the string column names:
val result = dataframe.select(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail: _*)

// or, equivalently, using Column objects:
val result = dataframe.select(columnNames.map(c => col(c)): _*)
```

Comment: `tail` returns the sequence excluding the first item (`head`); `: _*` transforms a collection into a vararg argument - used when calling a method expecting a vararg, like select does: `def select(col: String, cols: String*)`

Comment: It's called, repeated parameters, you can check more about it [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) - chapter 4 section 2.

Comment: @V.Samma that won't compile, check the signatures of `select` - it's either `select(col: String, cols: String*): DataFrame` for Strings, or `select(cols: Column*): DataFrame` for Columns, there's no `select(cols: String*): DataFrame`. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

Comment: Is there a way to add alias for other columns like this?        dataframe.select(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail: _*, col("abc").as("def")) ?

Answer (score 8):

Since `dataFrame.select()` expects a sequence of columns and we have a sequence of strings, we need to convert our sequence to a `List` of `col`s and convert that list to the sequence. `columnName.map(name => col(name)): _*` gives a sequence of columns from a sequence of strings, and this can be passed as a parameter to `select()`:

```
  val columnName = Seq("col1", "col2")
  val DFFiltered = DF.select(columnName.map(name => col(name)): _*)
```

Comment: Please add some context and explanation to this answer.

Comment: @UserszrKs i am using spark 2.3.1 version , when i use the above it is giving an error .."type mismatch : found: org.apache.spark.sql.Column , required :Seq[?] , What is wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can also write like this

```
val columnName = Seq("col1", "col2")
  val DFFiltered = DF.select(columnName.map(DF(_): _*)
```